# Why do I see the light in the reflection (EEVEE) even if the material is not reflective?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

As the title says...
I have a transparent (glass or full transmission in the principled shader) plane, but I see the reflection of my area-light although the material is not reflective. The only way it disappears is when I set the IOR on the plane to 1, which defeats the purpose of my setup.
Any ideas? Bug?
[image: why]

Comment: Glass **is** reflective.

Comment: Everything works like expected. You have set your glass to be perfectly reflective on the surface. That is what Roughness = 0 means. It is a perfect mirror surface with a glass volume behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual:

> The Glass BSDF node is used to add a Glass-like shader mixing refraction and reflection at grazing angles. [Glass BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shaders/nodes/types/shaders/glass.html?highlight=glass%20shader)

That's why you see reflections with this kind of shader.

If you don't need reflections on the object - use [Refraction BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shaders/nodes/types/shaders/refraction.html?highlight=refraction)

Comment: Accepted...although I don't get why it happens with the Principled BSDF with Transmission Full and Specular off....

Comment: Under the hood of Principled BSDF just mixing of other shaders.
Example from [Principled BSDF
 manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html)
> Transmission is Mix between fully opaque surface at zero and fully glass like transmission at one.

Answer (score 2):

All (smooth) surfaces in the real world become reflective at low angles of incidence, Eevee and cycles (with Principled shader) reproduce this, but Blender Render didn't.

As RUben says using a refraction BSDF will refract the light as if it entered a material of the same density of glass, without simulating the reflections that you would get when shining a light through real glass.